# How to set the title of a button from another view controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a view controller that allows the user to search for addresses, using `MKLocalSearchCompleter`, and the addresses pop up in a `tableView`. When the user clicks on an address in the `tableView`, I want to set a button's text in the previous view controller as the address clicked. I did this by setting the title from `MKLocalSearchCompletion` to a variable I created in the previous `viewController`. Then I've created a function in the previous `viewController` to set the variable as the button's title. Then I've called the function in the `viewController` which searched the button's address when within the `didSelectRowAt` function. Like this:

in `AddViewController` (the previous view controller):

```
@IBOutlet weak var AddressButton: UIButton!

struct addressButtonTitleStruct {
        static var addressButtonTitle: String = ""
    }
    
    func setAddressButton () {
        AddressButton.setTitle(addressButtonTitleStruct.addressButtonTitle, for: .normal)
    }
```

and in AddressSearchViewController (the one used to search for addresses that was presented):

```
 var searchResults = [MKLocalSearchCompletion]()

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        AddViewController.addressButtonTitleStruct.addressButtonTitle = searchResult.title
        AddViewController().setAddressButton()
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       
    }
```

However, no matter what I do- unplugging and then replugging the outlets, trying another outlet or trying the code on another view controller and another class- the app always crashes while trying to select a row: I get "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" on AddressButton. I've tested the variable and it shows up correctly all the ways to AddViewController, within the function setAddressButton. The only thing that doesn't seem to be working is the AddressButton itself, which shows up as `nil` in the variables in the debug area.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `AddViewController()` is not the instance you expect. It's a brand new instance without connected outlets hence the crash. You need the real reference to the storyboard instance. And please conform to the naming convention to name functions and variables with starting lowercase letter.

Comment: can you add a picture describes what you need to achieve ?

Comment: @vadian how should I reference the storyboard instance in my case?

Comment: It depends on how the controllers are related. Usual ways are segue, instantiation from storyboard, protocol/delegate and callback closure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! At the top of my head, I have two ways you can do that. I'll explain them to you and you decide what's best to your application, alright?

But before that, explaining your mistake, in this piece of code `AddViewController().setAddressButton()` you're actually creating a new instance of your view controller and calling the function. You're not using the preexisting view controller.

Unfortunately, billhack's answer has the same wrong approach, essentially creating a new instance of the view controller every time.

Ok, let's do it:

First, and actually tested by me:
Create a callback function on the second view controller like that:

```
var callBack:((_ buttonTitle: String) -> ())?
```

Make sure you set that variable with some value before popping the second view controller, like this:

```
callBack?("Some Title")
```

In the push function of the first view controller, write something like this:

```
@IBAction func pushToSecondVC(_ sender: Any) {
  if let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")as? SecondViewController {
  vc.callBack = { buttonName in
    self.setButtonName(buttonName)
  }
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
}
```

Second (as a guess of mine, I've not actually tried it), get the previous View controller and call the function:

```
let prev = self.presentingViewController
prev.callTheFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it to work! I used a callback function and did something a bit different from what you posted (I'll post that) but at least I found out what I need to do.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to upvote the answer if it was useful :) . Also I'm looking forward to see your approach

Answer (score 0):

To follow up vadian's comemnt, here is how to grab the right vc instance

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "mystoryboard", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCIdentifier")  as! VCType
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using a callback function like Savio suggested. I ended up calling my callback function a bit differently from what he did:

On the second view controller, the one that popped up and let me search addresses, I did this:

```
var callBack: ((_ addressButtonText: String) -> ())?

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let searchResult = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
       
        callBack?(searchResult.title)
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
       
    }
```

and on the first view controller, the one that presented the Address Search View Controller, I did this:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "AddViewControllerToAddressSearchViewController" {
            let popup = segue.destination as! AddressSearchViewController
            popup.callBack = setAddressButton(_:)
        }
    }
    
    
    func setAddressButton (_ addressButtonText: String) -> () {
        addressButton.setTitle(addressButtonText, for: .normal)
    }
```

This video really helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p80Kqj6rV50